# ¿Qué son las importaciones cíclicas o circulares en Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-import

estaba buscando información desde cero sobre este tema y no encuentro nada.
¿Alguien podría explicarme o mandarme un enlace dónde pueda entender qué son, para qué sirven y algún/os ejemplo/s de uso?

Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 4):

La mayor parte de las veces son un bug de implementación (o de diseño), por tanto no sirven para nada y no te puedo poner un ejemplo de uso :-)

Pero te puedo explicar mejor con un ejemplo cómo ocurren y cómo intentar evitarlas.

Una importación circular ocurre cuando desde un módulo A importas otro B (porque necesita una función o variable que está en B, pero a su vez el módulo B necesita usar una función o variable que está en el módulo A, por lo que también intenta importarlo.

```
# Modulo A
import B

def funcion_en_A():
    resultado = B.funcion_en_B()
    print(resultado)

A_CONFIG = "Hola"
```

```
# Modulo B

import A

def funcion_en_B():
    return A.A_CONFIG +  " mundo"
```

Es un ejemplo retorcido, pero la idea es que el módulo A define ciertas variables de configuración (`A_CONFIG`) y una función que invoca a otra que está en el módulo B. Pero el módulo B necesita importa A para acceder a `A_CONFIG`.

Si guardas ambos módulos e intentas escribir un programa que use A.funcion_en_A() como el siguiente:

```
# main
import A
A.funcion_en_A()
```

La idea es que debería salir "Hola mundo" (revisa el código para entender por qué). Si lo ejecutas podrás comprobar que es así. No ha habido error pese a la importación circular.

Sin embargo si cambiamos el ejemplo a esto otro:

```
# Modulo A
import B

def funcion_en_A():
    resultado = B.funcion_en_B()
    print(resultado)

def get_config():
    return {"msg": "Hola"}
```

```
# Modulo B
import A

CONFIG = A.get_config()
def funcion_en_B():
    return CONFIG["msg"] +  " mundo"
```

dejando `main.py` como estaba, al intentar ejecutarlo ahora tenemos un error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 2, in <module>
    import A
  File "/xxx/A.py", line 2, in <module>
    import B
  File "/xxx/B.py", line 4, in <module>
    CONFIG = A.get_config()
AttributeError: partially initialized module 'A' has no attribute 'get_config' (most likely due to a circular import)
```

Explicar por qué funcionó bien en el primer ejemplo pero ahora no, es complicado y exigiría explicar qué hace exactamente python ante un `import`. Pero la moraleja es clara: los import circulares pueden causar problemas.

Generalmente un import circular es síntoma de un mal diseño y la mejor solución suele ser repensar si realmente necesitamos separar en dos módulos esa funcionalidad o se puede tener todo en un solo módulo. En caso de que queramos tenerlo separado, una solución puede ser cambiar el punto en que se hace uno de los imports, retrasándolo hasta el momento en que es realmente necesario. En este ejemplo, la `funcion_en_A()` necesita una `funcion_en_B()` pero el `import B` puede hacerse dentro de la función en vez de fuera, y eso arreglaría el problema:

```
# Modulo A

def funcion_en_A():
    import B
    resultado = B.funcion_en_B()
    print(resultado)

def get_config():
    return {"msg": "Hola"}
```

También, aunque resulte sorprendente, el módulo A funcionará correctamente si se importa B al final en vez de al principio:

```
# Modulo A

def funcion_en_A():
    resultado = B.funcion_en_B()
    print(resultado)

def get_config():
    return {"msg": "Hola"}

import B
```

y esto también resuelve el error de la dependencia circular.